# Bitvise SSH Client command line (stnlc.exe) gets error while the one with GUI successfully connected

Tags: command-line, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm integrating Bitvise client into my winform app. I am using Bitvise SSH Client command line (stnlc.exe in the app's directory) to do so. My app needs to have multiple connections at the same time.
It works well with some addresses, but some other it doesn't. This is the command that I'm using:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client\stnlc.exe" -profile="C:\Users\AutoOffer\AutoOffer\bin\Debug\data\sshprofile.bscp" -host=<myhost> -port=22 -user=<username> -pw=<password> -ka=y -proxyFwding=y -proxyListIntf=127.0.0.1 -proxyListPort=<port>
```

And this is the error I got:

```
Bitvise SSH Client 6.45 - stnlc - free for individual use only, see EULA
Copyright (C) 2000-2015 by Bitvise Limited.

Connecting to SSH2 server XX.XX.XX.XX:22.
Connection established.
Server version: SSH-2.0-dropbear_0.46
First key exchange started.
ERROR: The SSH2 session has terminated with error.
Reason: Error class: LocalSshDisconn, code: KeyExchangeFailed, message: FlowSshTransport: no mutually supported key exchange algorithm.
Local list: "ecdh-sha2-1.3.132.0.10,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1".
Remote list: "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1".
```

I tried to connect manually by the Bitvise app with GUI and it successfully connected!
I also updated my bitvise version to the latest (6.45).

Comment: *no mutually supported key exchange algorithm* server supports different Kex than your client. What Kex is used when you connect using GUI. There must be some log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Local list: "ecdh-sha2-1.3.132.0.10,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1".
Remote list: "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1".
```

So it looks like the remote side just supports `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`, which is not supported on your side.

On [Bitvise SSH Server Version History](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-version-history) I read:

> The 1024-bit fixed prime Diffie Hellman key exchange methods, diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 and gssapi-group1-sha1 with Kerberos 5, are now disabled by default, due to doubts about continuing security of Diffie Hellman with a 1024-bit fixed prime. Compatibility with most older clients should be retained via the diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 method, which uses a 2048-bit fixed prime. We recommend migrating older SSH clients to new versions supporting ECDH and ECDSA.

So it looks like you have to modify the settings and allow 1024-bit fixed prime Diffie Hellman key exchange methods. Otherwise you will not be able to connect. As explained it is of course better to change the ssh server settings.

Comment: I added diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 to my profile and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @FlySoFast how? where is the settings file? Can I do it using command line?

Comment: @Toolkit If I remember correctly, I used the GUI app to add the missing algorithm to a profile, and then run the command line using that profile.

Comment: oh man bitvise is such a pain, I've switched to https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET there are some tweaks to be done still way better

Answer (score 0):

Also, please note that running `stnlc` as a service is a possibility. With it, the tunnel can be started even without the user having to log on, and can be restarted upon dropping.

Be aware that wrapping and running `stnlc` as a service (using eg. `nssm` or `winsw`) *absolutely requires* adding the **`unat=y`** option to prevent the service from going interactive and failing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error working with BitWise Tunnelier:

*The SSH connection has terminated with error. Reason: Error class: LocalSshDisconn, code: KeyExchangeFailed, message: FlowSshTransport: no mutually supported key exchange algorithm.*

For me the solution was to increase the **DH gex min bits** in the SSH tab, from 1023 to 2047.

The server side suffered some changes/updates.